Error on calling delete method on object in django
I have a stage model defined as below. When I try to perform delete operation I am getting below error. For other models, delete is working fine.
previously I have been using django 2.2. After Upgrade I am seeing this error.
from djangodeletes.softdeletes import (
    SoftDeletable,
    SoftDeleteManager,
    SoftDeleteQuerySet,
)

class Stage(SoftDeletable, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stage_type = models.CharField(
        choices=STAGE_TYPE_CHOICES,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=50,
    )
    close_stage_type = models.CharField(
        choices=CLOSE_STAGE_TYPE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=20,
    )
    sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    pipeline = models.ForeignKey(
        Pipeline,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="pipeline_stages",
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.User",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="stage_created_by",
    )

    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.User",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="stage_modified_by",
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = SoftDeleteManager.from_queryset(SoftDeleteQuerySet)()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


Stage.objects.get(id = 1240).delete()

  File "/home/srinivas/design_studio_app_1/design_studio_app/prac.py", line 50, in <module>
    stage.delete()
  File "/home/srinivas/design_studio_app_1/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djangodeletes/softdeletes/models.py", line 78, in delete
    for (field, value), instances in instances_for_fieldvalues.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'```

I am using below versions
Python 3.8.18, Django 4.2.9, djangodeletes 0.43
what could be the issue?

The package you are using for soft deletes is unmaintained, find an alternative or implement the soft deletes on your own.
